# How to convert a Byte* from C++ to Byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pinvoke

I have a library in C++ containing a library returning a Byte* :

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;
Byte* RotateImage90(Byte* data, int w, int h);
```

I'm using this library in a program in C# (Xamarin) :

```
[DllImport("libCpp", EntryPoint = "RotateImage90")]
public static extern IntPtr rotate90(byte[] data, int w, int h);

Byte[] test(Byte[] data, int w, int h)
{
    IntPtr ptr = rotate90(data, w, h);
    Byte[] img = ????;// <= function missing
    return img;
}
```

It works good, but I don't know how to convert the pointer to a Byte array. Someone know a function to do that ?

Comment: This function is impossible to use correctly in a C++ program, that does not get better when you pinvoke it.

Comment: It seams that it work in C++. I added a breakpoint in my function `RotateImage90` (in C++) and it received a pointer, I checked values, it correspond to values in `data` sent by C#.

Comment: Who frees up the byte array returned by the C++ code? And how do you know how many bytes to read at the address pointed by the pointer? Is the returned pointer the same as the byte array going in?

Comment: @xxbbcc the byte array returned as same size, height and width are reversed (it's a image rotation ). So I know number of bytes to read. C++ function return a pointer for the new image. The C# fonction have to get all bytes in a array and have to free it at the end.

Comment: @A.Pissicat If you're controlling both sources (C++ / C#) I strongly suggest you change the C++ call interface. If you don't control the C++ source, this will become a maintenance nightmare for you.

Comment: @xxbbcc I'm actually developing the C++ library. I received a Byte[] and I have to return a new Byte[].
I'm using C#/xamarin to test interface but the library will be used with java too. So returning the pointer is the only way I found.

Comment: Don't return a pointer but force the caller to pass in an already-allocated byte array (along with the size). Return the number of bytes written to the byte array. This way the caller can allocate / free the array any way they see fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem of your function interface is that the memory that the function dynamically allocates to return the rotated image byte array, must be allocated with the *same* memory allocator that the C# side (or whatever client code) will use to release the memory.

In other words, the module that allocates the memory and the module that frees it must use the *same* allocator.

When I needed to pass some array data between native code and C# code I successfully used **Safe Arrays**. On the C++ side, you can use ATL's `CComSafeArray` to [simplify the safe array programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt795188.aspx); on the other hand, C# and the CLR understand safe arrays well, so it's easy to get the array data in C# and consume it in managed code.

You can use a function like this to produce a safe array of bytes in C++ (in your case, the safe array will store the rotated image data):

```
extern "C" HRESULT __stdcall ProduceSafeArrayOfBytes(/* [out] */ SAFEARRAY** ppsa)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    try
    { 
        // Create the safe array to be returned to the caller
        CComSafeArray<BYTE> sa( /* Element count */);

        // Fill the safe array data.
        // You can use a simple sa[i] syntax,
        // where 'i' is a 0-based index
        ...

        // Return the safe array to the caller (transfer ownership)
        *ppsa = sa.Detach();
    }
    // Convert exceptions to HRESULT return codes
    catch (const CAtlException& e)
    {
        hr = e;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& )
    { 
        hr = E_FAIL;
    }

    return hr;
}
```

On the C# side, you can use this PInvoke signature:

```
[DllImport("NativeDll.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern void ProduceSafeArrayOfBytes(
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_UI1)]
    out byte[] result
);
```

The `VT_UI1` enum field tells the .NET Marshaller that the safe array contains bytes.

You can get the array data in C# with simple code like this:

```
byte[] data;
ProduceSafeArrayOfBytes(out data);
```

As you can see, in your C# code you deal with a simple `byte[]` array; all the proper data marshalling (including freeing memory) happens automatically under the hood.

You can modify the aforementioned skeleton code, adding the other function parameters, like your image width and height.

---

As an alternative, another option would be developing a tiny bridging layer using **C++/CLI**, to convert from raw C-style arrays to .NET managed arrays.

Anyway, the note on your DLL function interface to use a common memory allocator for allocating and releasing the array memory is still valid.

---

As a third option, if you can modify your DLL function interface, you can require the caller to allocate an array and pass it to the DLL function. The function will write the result data in this **caller-allocated array**.

This would simplify the memory management, as you give the DLL function a block of memory that is *already* allocated by the caller. The caller will have the responsibility for both allocating and releasing that memory.

So, your DLL function would look like this:

```
extern "C" void __cdecl RotateImage90(Byte* result, Byte* data, int width, int height);
```

The result array is allocated by the caller, who is also responsible to free it.
The function just writes its output in this caller-allocated array.

PInvoke would look like this:

```
[DllImport("NativeDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void RotateImage90(byte[] result, byte[] data, int width, int height);
```

Comment: .net also understands raw byte arrays (when used correctly), SAFEARRAY are a bit overkill if nothing (read: COM, Automation clients, VB/VBA/Scripts, etc.) forces you to use them.